# OData not setting all expand when using $inlinecount

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using OData 3 from MS in a WebAPI Controller.

My controller looks like this:

```
public override IEnumerable<WorkOrderModel> Get(ODataQueryOptions<WorkOrderModel> options)
{
    Int64? totalCount;
    var results = _workOrders.Get(options, out totalCount);

    options.ApplyTo(results.AsQueryable());

    return new PageResult<WorkOrderModel>(results,
        Request.ODataProperties()
               .NextLink,
        totalCount);
}
```

And I run this query:
`/odata/WorkOrders?$expand=ItemSerial`

I get the correct results, all WorkOrders will give me the correct ItemSerial.

But when I run this:
`/odata/WorkOrders?$expand=ItemSerial&$inlinecount=allpages`

Only some of the work orders will have an Item Serial. It's not random, it's always the same ones, but I can't figure out a pattern.

I HAVE to to the `ApplyTo` otherwise I will never get the expansions back from OData.

If I inspect `var results` then I can see that all results have an `ItemSerial`, but after `options.ApplyTo(results.AsQueryable());` most of them are set to null.

Is there a known bug in the ODataQueryOptions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these code below:

```
var queryResult = options.ApplyTo(results.AsQueryable());
```

you may find that your WOrkOrders are always expand even you remove the `$expand=ItemSerial`, because you didn't use the result of `ApplyTo` function.

Comment: I tried that yeah, but even then it's no good. I managed to track it down to a function in the OData framework where it counts the results of the set, but in the same time destroys all includes. I now set the TotalCount by hand it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in OData from MS. You can prevent this from happening by manually setting the `ResultCount` to a number before doing `ApplyTo`.